# Can TestFlight binary be misused by users?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, jailbreak, testflight

I need to know if I give a binary for testing to Test Flight users, is it possible for them to extract the ipa on jail broken iPhone, resign it with their own distribution certificate and submit it to Appstore? I read TestFlight distributes thinned binaries so that might make job difficult but I am not an expert (I have seen few ripoffs in the AppStore before though).

Comment: DOn't worry. You can also generate an IPA file (Build and Archive / share) and send it to your tester. S/He will be able to install it to his device using Itunes.

If his device is not jailbroken then you will need to add his UDID to the mobile provisioning you are using to sign the application.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not possible...

All ipa with sign with there own certificate, so don't worry...

Comment: I have seen few years back people posting ripoffs of successful apps by signing with their own certificate, how is it possible?

Comment: there are ways to resign the app. Apple also provides script for app resigning. There are third party services also available as Fastlane.